# class 'App\Mail\VerifyMail' not found in laravel

Tags: laravel, smtp, phpmailer, laravel-mail

Laravel keeps throwing an error that App\Mail\VerifyMail does not exit but that file exists in App\Mail folder. I don't know why it keeps telling me that it does not exist when it clear does;

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\User;
use App\Mail\VerifyMail;
use App\VerifyUser;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

class UserRegisterController extends Controller
{
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest:user');
}

public function showRegisterForm() {
    return view('user.registerForm');
}

public function register(Request $request) {
    $userValidated = $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'email' => 'required|string|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed'
    ]);

    $register = [
        'name' => $userValidated['name'],
        'email' => $userValidated['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($userValidated['password']),
    ];

    $user =User::create($register);
    VerifyUser::create([
        'token' => str::random(60),
        'user_id' => $user->id,
    ]);
    Mail::to($user->email)->send(new VerifyMail($user));

    return redirect('user/login')->with('email', 'An email was sent to you for verification');
}

public function verifyEmail($token, $date) {
    $dates = date(strtotime($date));
    if(time() - $dates > 60 * 60) {
        return redirect('/user/login')->with('failed' , 'Oops! Something went wrong');
    }
    $verifiedUser = VerifyUser::where('token', $token)->firstOrFail();
    if(isset($verifiedUser)) {
        $user = $verifiedUser->user;
        if($user->email_verified_at == '') {
            $user->email_verified_at = carbon::now();
            $user->save();

            return redirect('/user/login')->with('success', 'Your email was successfully verified');
        } else {
            return redirect('/user/login')->with('failed' , 'Oops! Something went wrong');
        }
    }
}
}
```

As you can see in this code i have included the class like App\Mail\VerifyMail. Spellings also clearly match nothing wrong with them.
Mail::to($user->email)->send(new VerifyMail($user));
This is how i use that class in my code.

This is my VerifyMail class

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class VerifyMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public $user;
public function __construct($user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.verifyEmail')->with('user', $this->user);
}
}
```

Comment: Defining a namespace import (what `use` does) does not mean that the class exists or is loadable.

Comment: What is the content of the VerifyMail class?

Comment: I uploaded the whole class too

Comment: @Synchro I know (use) does not mean that class exists but i created that class myself and i am telling you that it exists

Comment: The difference between what you think is happening and what is actually happening is more commonly known as a bug. Don’t assume, check. And do a `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Yeah bro that fixed it. Can you tell me what this code does as i am still learning laravel.